# Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - how does this affect our [imgur-maze]s?

Tags: discussion

[Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395024/278659)

> Since 2010, Imgur has provided image hosting services to Stack Exchange, but that hosting contract with Imgur comes to an end this upcoming April 2024. [...] Imgur no longer provides an enterprise image hosting product, and therefore, it has come time to find an alternative solution. [...]
>
> We are working on a plan to develop a solution to the image hosting problem. The exact implementation details are still being finalized, and we are in the research and discovery phase for a new image hosting solution. An internal proof-of-concept will inform the image hosting provider we ultimately settle on, and we expect this preliminary work to conclude some time in December of this year. Once our image hosting concept is proven out, we will transition to developing the solution we’d like to hold for the long term. We are aiming to complete core work on this new solution before the end of March 2024. However, as we are in the proof of concept stage, this schedule may shift considerably.
>
> Some time in late December or early January, after proof-of-concept work completes, I will update this post to contain more details on how our solution will work, the sort of impact it will have on the network (if any - ideally very little), and the timeline on which that work will be completed.

Obviously, this is something we'll need to think about particularly closely here on PSE, as we have an [entire tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imgur-maze) for puzzles based around the concept of Stack.Imgur images and their URLs (and a lot more than those 25 questions, other puzzles that don't have the tag but involve Imgur mazes in a not-immediately-obvious way).

Fear not, SE staff have been made aware of our site-specific issue in that main meta post. [wizzwizz4 explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395027/278659) that "a few multi-part Puzzling questions rely on the codes remaining the same", and this is mentioned again in [the highest-voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395026/278659) on the thread. In a comment, SE employee Kyle Pollard mentions that he "plan[s] on keeping the exact same IDs", so *hopefully* this won't be a huge deal-breaking issue for our [imgur-maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imgur-maze) puzzles.

The purpose of *this* PSE-specific meta post is:

- to **inform the PSE community**, in case they haven't seen the main meta post (it's not featured), especially those in the process of creating new [imgur-maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imgur-maze) puzzles;
- to figure out if there's **anything else we should inform SE staff** to take into account when planning how to manage the transition away from Imgur for image hosting;
- to decide if there's **anything that our site specifically should do** to prepare for the change (e.g. I think we should at least ask mods to change the tag name, and certainly the tag description, and perhaps consider editing some/all of the posts with this tag, but hopefully not mass-close those puzzles as no longer viable!)

Comment: The new tag should probably be [image-maze]. (I personally have a strong aversion to puzzles of this kind and some part of me is sad that the transition is apparently not going to destroy them all, but that's just me...)